# Set environment variable in makefile read by jom / nmake

Tags: windows, qt, makefile, environment-variables, nmake

I have a makefile, which is designed to work with nmake (in a ms visual studio command  line prompt). The `makefile` itself sets an environment variable `MY_SAY_SOMETHING` needed for other tools like a batchfile `test.bat`. This works very fine with `nmake`.

However, I want to use Qt's `jom` instead to speed up my build process by usage of several processor cores with the option `-J`. The tool `jom`is considered to be a clone of `nmake` according to Qt it, so the `makefile` should be compatible.

***The problem is***: `jom` does not set environment variables on a windows machine! At least not in the way the nmake supports it.

***So my question is:*** How do I set an environment variable with `jom`?

---

This is the shortest possible example showing my problem:

**makefile:**

```
!IF [set MY_SAY_SOMETHING="my super message"]
!ENDIF

all:
    @test.bat
```

**test.bat:**

```
@echo off
echo THIS IS MY SUPER MESSAGE "%MY_SAY_SOMETHING%"
```

---

Now I'm just calling the makefile with nmake (from the visual studio command line prompt). This looks like this:

> D:\> nmake
>
> Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 10.00.30319.01
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> THIS IS MY SUPER MESSAGE ""my super message""

When I'm calling jom (either from the visual studio command line prompt or a regular windows cmd.exe prompt), I just get this:

> D:\> jom
>
> jom 1.1.3 - empower your cores
>
> THIS IS MY SUPER MESSAGE ""

I also called the `-P` option for `nmake` and `jom` to get more information about how the makefile is interpreted. However, my environment variable was printed with `nmake`, but not with `jom`. I also tried the option `-E` (override environment variable macros) with the same result.

Maybe it is just a bug in `jom`...

Comment: I have posted a _second_ answer, which may be more useful than my first.

Comment: Perhaps I have misunderstood your question, or maybe my answer(s) do not suit your environment? It might be helpful if you could add some more info. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** This is my first answer, exploring three ideas which do *not* work. See my second answer for an actual solution.

---

This is more of a comment than an answer, but it does suggest a work-around.

The output of the following makefile:

```
!IF [echo Test 1:] && [set MY_SAY_SOMETHING="my super message"] && [set MY]
!ENDIF

!IF [echo Test 2: && set MY_SAY_SOMETHING="my unsuper message" && set MY]
!ENDIF

WORK_AROUND = set MY_SAY_SOMETHING="this is a possible work-around"

all:
    @echo Test 3:
    @-call set MY
    @test.bat
    @echo Test 4:
    @$(WORK_AROUND)
    @call set MY
    @test.bat
```

is for `nmake`:

```
>nmake

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.10.25019.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Test 1:
MY_SAY_SOMETHING="my super message"
Test 2:
MY_SAY_SOMETHING="my unsuper message"
Test 3:
MY_SAY_SOMETHING="my super message"
THIS IS MY SUPER MESSAGE ""my super message""
Test 4:
MY_SAY_SOMETHING="this is a possible work-around"
THIS IS MY SUPER MESSAGE ""this is a possible work-around""
```

and for `jom`:

```
>jom
Test 1:
Environment variable MY not defined
Test 2:
MY_SAY_SOMETHING="my unsuper message"

jom 1.1.3 - empower your cores

Test 3:
Environment variable MY not defined
THIS IS MY SUPER MESSAGE ""
Test 4:
MY_SAY_SOMETHING="this is a possible work-around"
THIS IS MY SUPER MESSAGE ""this is a possible work-around""
```

**Note 1**:  For `nmake`, the output of Test 2 is what I would expect, but it doesn't "take". The `set MY` in Test 3 gives what was set in Test 1.

**Note 2**:  For `jom`, Test 2 gives the desired output, but again it doesn't "take". And Test 1 fails.

**Note 3:**  In the recipe, the `call` is needed for `jom` for `set MY` to work. It is optional for `nmake`.

Answer (score 0):

The makefile:

```
all: .MY_ENVIRONMENT
    @test.bat

.MY_ENVIRONMENT:
    @set MY_SAY_SOMETHING="my super message"
```

will work with both `nmake` and `jom`:

```
>nmake -l
THIS IS MY SUPER MESSAGE ""my super message""

>jom -l
THIS IS MY SUPER MESSAGE ""my super message""
```

Comment: Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1198 and GNU Make 3.81. I cant set env vars for process, runned by the make-uitlity. The var has empty value in the same make-recipe. 
@set qwe=asd, echo qwe=%qwe%

Comment: @Solo.dmitry: This question concerns `nmake` and `jom`, not `gmake`.

Answer (score 0):

In the Makefile you can write:

```
!IF [call set MY_SAY_SOMETHING="my super message"]
!ENDIF
```

This should not break nmake, but fixes JOM.